# Memory management with background service

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I created an application that creates a background service. When I close the application the service is running and when I go back to get it back to "bind" (bindService) to it for communications.

The problem is that when I close the application and re-enter, it significantly increases the memory in use. Spend 20Mb -> 24Mb, if I go out and come 24Mb -> 28Mb, 28Mb -> 30Mb ... Thus breaking up the application. I have no bitmaps. That if enough use static arrays but I've tested and are not the source of the problem.

When I close the application completely (including service) call System.exit(0) and clean all the memory, but of course, I can call when I leave the service running as it closes. I tried to call the Garbage Collector (System.gc()) and if I notice that memory decreases to close, but when you open the application again same memory increases.

I would greatly appreciate the help, Bye!

Answer (score 1):

Considering information we have, I suspect the problem is an Activity leak.
Can you please check 2 things:

1. Check carefully do you use Activity Context (reference to Activity) that can be stored? Particularly in Service.
2. Try to make an experiment - select "Do not keep activities" in Developer setting - will the memory be decreasing after each Activity launch?

Comment: I selected "destroy activities" and have not been successful. The memory increases to re-enter the application when the service is active.
I do not store any reference to the Activity in Service . I can not figure out where this increase can come from memory.

Comment: Ok, in this case I can only recommend to start memory profiling. Luckily, Android have many tools for that, I would recommend starting with this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html
If it will not be hard - can you share the results of the investigation? Good luck.

Comment: Not very inforamative, right? Can be please check "Creating a heap dump" paragraph in the article and try to use MAT to check the heap? It should provide more details for allocations.

Comment: This is the dominator tree: http://i.imgur.com/SLAgS.png and this is the histogram: http://i.imgur.com/vYVOV.png.

Comment: I have analyzed the application point by point and memory load slowly. Can it be that Android does not clear the memory when Activity ends that have a service running?

Comment: Basically yes, it can keep activities as long as it wants. But if you'd set "Destroy activities" in settings - so it must destroy activity after each onStop().
However, am I right that now memory usage increasing slowly, and before it was heacy increases after each launch? Is that a result of DestroyActivities, or you'd made something else?

Comment: No, not increase more slowly if I have enabled the option to "destroy activities". I do not understand that can cause increased memory: (

Comment: Can you carefully check around all static variables(do you have any) and all passing to Service? Maybe you pass there something that can reference to your activity? For example, any Drawable, passed to service, will cause significant leak, if it was previously setted as a background to any View.. Or maybe there are some threads/tasks that can hold some references?

Comment: At the beginning of the application I create static variables (in ArrayList). The service uses some of them. When I close the application variables declared as "null" and call System.gc()